# React Protected Route does not show component

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm just beginner for React. Now, I'm trying to protect route and there's no error and nothing on the console that could explain what's wrong why it doesn't show the component as it should be.
Here are my codes.

```
//App.js
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { BrowserRouter, Route, Switch } from 'react-router-dom';
import Login from './Login';
import Dashboard from './Dashboard';
import { ProtectedRoute } from './ProtectedRoute';
import Logout from './Logout';

export default class App extends Component {

  render() {
    return (
      <BrowserRouter>
        <Switch>
          <Route exact path="/" component={Login} />
          <ProtectedRoute path="/dashboard" component={Dashboard} />
          <Route path="/logout" component={Logout} />
          <Route path="*" component={() => "404 NOT FOUND"} />
        </Switch>
      </BrowserRouter>
    )
  }
}
```

```
//ProtectedRoute.js
import React from 'react';
import { Route, Redirect } from 'react-router-dom';
import auth from './auth';

export const ProtectedRoute = ({ component: Component, ...rest }) => {
    return(
        <Route 
            {...rest}
            render = {props => {          
                auth.isAuthenticated().then(resp => 
                    resp === true ? (<Component {...props} {...rest} />) : (
                        <Redirect to={
                            {
                                pathname: "/",
                                state: {
                                    from: props.location
                                }
                            }
                        } />                        
                    ) 
                ).catch(error => {
                    alert(error);
                });
            }}
        />
    );
};
```

...

```
//auth.js
import axios from 'axios';

axios.defaults.withCredentials = true;

class Auth {

    constructor(){
        this.host = 'http://' + window.location.hostname + ':5000';
    }

    isAuthenticated(){
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            axios.get(`${this.host}/getsignin`).then(resp => {
                console.log('resp.data from isAuthenticated() : '+resp.data);
                resolve(resp.data)
            }).catch(error => {
                reject(error);
            });
        });
    }

    login(username, password){
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            axios.post(`${this.host}/signin`, {
                user: username,
                password: password
            }).then(resp => {
                let rs = JSON.stringify(resp.data);
                if(rs === "1"){
                    resolve(true);
                }else{
                    resolve(false);
                }
            }).catch(error => {
                reject(error);
            });
        });
    }
}

export default new Auth();
```

...

```
//Login.js
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import $ from 'jquery';
import { WaveLoading } from 'react-loadingg';
import auth from './apis/auth';
import { Redirect } from 'react-router';

export default class Login extends Component {

    constructor(props){
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            redirect: false,
            loading: true
        }
        this.onSubmit = this.onSubmit.bind(this);
    }

    onSubmit(){
        auth.login($('#txtUser').val(), $('#txtPass').val())
        .then(resp => {
            this.setState({
                redirect : resp
            });
        }).catch(error => {
            alert(error);
        });        
    }

    showLogin(){
        return(
            <div className="hold-transition login-page">
                <div className="login-box">
                    <div className="login-logo">
                        <a href="LINK"><b>KVC Computer</b></a>
                    </div>
                    <div className="card">
                        <div className="card-body login-card-body">
                            <p className="login-box-msg">Sign in</p>
                            <div className="input-group mb-3">
                                <input type="text" className="form-control" placeholder="Username" name="txtUser" id="txtUser" />
                                <div className="input-group-append">
                                    <div className="input-group-text">
                                        <span className="fas fa-user" />
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div className="input-group mb-3">
                                <input type="password" className="form-control" placeholder="Password" name="txtPass" id="txtPass" />
                                <div className="input-group-append">
                                    <div className="input-group-text">
                                        <span className="fas fa-lock" />
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div className="row">
                                <div className="col-8">
                                    <div className="icheck-primary">
                                        <input type="checkbox" id="chkRem" name="chkRem" />
                                        <label htmlFor="remember">
                                            Remember Me
                                        </label>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div className="col-4">
                                    <button className="btn btn-primary btn-block" name="btnSignin" id="btnSignin" onClick={this.onSubmit}>Sign In</button>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div className="social-auth-links text-center mb-3">
                                <p>- OR -</p>
                            </div>
                            <p className="mb-1">
                                <a href="forgot-password.html" name="btnForgot" id="btnForgot">forgot your password</a>
                            </p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>                
            </div>
        )
    }

    componentDidMount(){
        this.setState({ loading : false });
        auth.isAuthenticated().then(res => {
            this.setState({ redirect : res });
            console.log('isAuthenticat : '+res);
        })
    }

    render() {
        if(this.state.redirect){
            return <Redirect to="/dashboard" />;
        }
        return (
            this.state.loading ? <WaveLoading /> : this.showLogin()
        )
    }
}
```

Login.js -> If user already login then redirect to dashboard

```
//Dashboard.js
import React, { Component } from 'react';

export default class Dashboard extends Component {

    constructor(props){
        super(props);
        console.log('constructor');
    }

    componentDidMount(){
        console.log('componentDidMount');
    }

    onRender = () => {
        return (
            <div>
                <h1>This is dashboard!!</h1>
            </div>
        );
    }


    render() {
        console.log('render');
        return (
            this.onRender()
        )
    }
}
```

After user has logged in Auth.isAuthenticated() return true and ProtectedRoute should return Component to App (Dashboard). It shows nothing on the browser but the url is http://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx/dashboard

I have no idea why is that happend and how to solve this. Should I change some code?
I'm stuck on this for days.

Thanks

Comment: You aren't using the same instance of the `Auth` class for logging in and checking `isAuthenticated`.

Comment: You also can't return things promises in `render()`